# Exception thrown on Await Task

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I'm new to Async functions and I'm learning it. I have written code that returns a value from an Async function and prints it to the console. Upon running the code a get `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException` on `Dim result As Integer = Await task` and I don't know why. This is my code:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim task = New Task(AddressOf testAync)
        task.Start()
        task.Wait()
    End Sub

    Async Sub testAync()
        Dim task As Task(Of Integer) = HandleFileAsync(9000)
        Dim result As Integer = Await task
        Console.WriteLine(result)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Async Function HandleFileAsync(ByVal x As Integer) As Task(Of Integer)
        Return Await Task.Run(aFunction(x))
    End Function

    Public Function aFunction(ByVal intIn)
        Return intIn
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue lies in `HandleFileAsync`, where you are awaiting the running of the synchronous function `aFunction`. I am not sure why you are not explicitly typing your parameter and return value in that function, but at the end of the day it doesn't really relate to your problem so I will ignore.

Since `aFunction` is not asynchronous, you do not need to await it or create a task. Your error is that `Task.Run(aFunction(x))` is expecting an asynchronous `Action`, or a function that returns an asynchronous `Task`.

Simply modify `HandleFileAsync` to the following:

```
Async Function HandleFileAsync(ByVal x As Integer) As Task(Of Integer)
    Return  aFunction(x)
End Function
```